# TriggerToolkit is damaged and can't be opened

Tags: trigger.io

On OSX Mavericks I'm trying to open the TriggerToolkit app and am getting:
"TriggerToolkit is damaged and can't be opened."

I've tried redownloading, same issue.

Here's a screenshot:
http://cl.ly/image/3G0l2S471d0M

Comment: You can workaround this by going to “settings > security & privacy > allow apps downloaded from > anywhere”. Sorry about this problem - we're working on a fix with our code signing to support Mavericks without needing you to do that in the future.

Amir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was caused by a signing issue with OSX Mavericks - we have since updated to Toolkit build and this is resolved.

Go to https://trigger.io/forge/toolkit to download and install the latest Toolkit.